FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT does not work
I have an activity called ChatActivity but it has strange life cycle. When it is first created, the first instance (ChatActivity1) is created and the methods being call is as the below:
    ChatActivity1 onCreate()
    ChatActivity1 onResume()

Now I press the home button, this instance enters pause state:
    ChatActivity1 onPause()

Then I get a notification on the launcher, and if I press the notification on the launcher, it launches MainActivity where these is a code snippet to start the ChatActivity.
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ChatActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
    activity.startActivityIfNeeded(intent,0);

A new instance (ChatActivity2) will be launched and the old one (ChatActivity1) is deleted:
    ChatActivity2 onCreate()
    ChatActivity2 onResume()
    ChatActivity1 onResume()
    ChatActivity1 onPause()
    ChatActivity1 onDestroy()

My question is: how do I resume the ChatActivity1 without creating ChatActivity2?  FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT does not seem to work.
Here's my AndroidManifest.xml.
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ChatActivity">
        </activity>

I've tried
   intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT);
But it does not work either. It still creates a new instance instead of reusing the existing instance.

Please edit your question and post the code you use to create the Notification, including the code that creates the PendingIntent in the Notification.

Please also ignore the suggestion to use special launch modes singleTask or singleInstance as these are only required for very special situations (HOME screen replacements) and usually create more problems than they solve.

How do you expect this to work? If the current task contains MainActivity at the root, and ChatActivity on top of that, and then you launch MainActivity again (from the Notification, what do you think will happen? Either the existing instance of MainActivity will be shown to the user (in which case the existing instance of ChatActivity would have to be removed), or a new instance of MainActivity would need to be created and placed on top of the existing instances of MainActivity and ChatActivity. You need to rethink your architecture. Explain whagt you want to do.

 <activity
          android:name=".MainActivity"
          android:launchMode="singleTask">
      </activity>
      <activity
          android:name=".ChatActivity">
          android:launchMode="singleTop">
      </activity>

try this this should work

Not a good idea. Special launch modes singleTask and singleInstance are not necessary in normal applications and tend to create more problems than they solve. There are better ways to solve these problems using default and well-understood Android behaviours.

how can we solve this without using these tags can you elaborate more plz

Sure, first I need to understand what OP wants to happen. His architecture is not correct.
